# React Bootstrap Navbar in 2 rows

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve something like this using react-bootstrap.

Desktop View:

```
---------------------------------
Logo - Site Name
Link1 Link2 Link3 Link4
---------------------------------
```

Mobile View:

```
---------------------------------
Logo - Site Name       Hamburger
---------------------------------
```

Example code given by react-bootstrap:

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Container>
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="me-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

I've tried adding flex column, Row, br etc, in between the Brand and Toggle, but none of them gave me the desired output. Either menu comes to the second line, or it doesn't expand when stayed in the first line.

Anyone has any suggestions to achieve this?